# When to use RTL and LTR?

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, chat, whatsapp

I want to know how to use RTL and LTR in android studio.
When and why to use it in android?
Can we use it to create WhatsApp's chat interface?
Thank you.

[image]

[image]

Comment: **NO**. RTL is meant for languages like Arabic. You have to play with the View **alignment**, instead.

Comment: Please I also want to know why when i use 
TextView.setText(mysTex+"        ") ; some time,the tabulations doesn't appear to the textView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the languages such as Arabic, Hebrew etc follow a right to left pattern. Android 4.2+ (JellyBean API 17+) supports RTL layouts.

For API 17+ in the XML files all the layouts that need RTL support should replace layout_marginLeft/paddingLeft with layout_marginStart/paddingStart and layout_marginRight/paddingRight with layout_marginEnd/paddingEnd
For API 17 below add start and end layout properties along with left and right.

The manifest needs to include android:supportsRtl="true" to the  tag.

WhatsApp chat interface has the friends text and your text aligned to left and right respectively by setting the TextView/TextBox gravity. Within the textview the text is aligned from left to right irrespective of whether the textview is to the left or right of the view. If the person uses Arabic or Hebrew to chat this alignment of friends textview to the left and ours to the right will not change but the alignment of the text inside the textview will be aligned from right to left.